# Is this a bleeder? Why won't it close?

Tags: plumbing, baseboard

[image: Is this a bleeder?]
In trying to repair a pipe I went to empty my baseboard heating system, and so I tried to open what I thought was a bleeder.  It didn't seem to make any difference, and now after unbolting it it will not thread back in.

Is this actually a bleeder?  Either way, any idea why it won't close?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a [balancing valve](http://www.ebertmachine.com/balancingvalves.html), and you have probably got the guts of it confused with excessive unscrewing. You may be able to sort them out if you undo the BIG nut and take them out. if not, a heating professional can.

The purpose of this type of valve is to balance flow between heating loops, so it will also need to be re-adjusted once reassembled (or replaced.) The lack of a handle is intended to keep it from being fiddled with by the average homeowner, as it is a "set and forget" device if adjusted properly in the first place.

Hint for the future - bleeders don't face down.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just couldn't find bleeders anywhere else so I thought this would work. Got the heating company coming soon, but is it okay to turn on the water the way the valve is?

Comment: Given that you or they are probably going to have to take it further apart to sort it out, I'd leave it empty for now.

Comment: It looks really solar to nozzle pressure setting valve on my oil boiler... Something that the average homeowner has no business messing with (ask me how I know!). The heating guy will probably attach pressure gauges here and there and set that to get the right balance.